# Iterate suggestions list of PrimeFaces Autocomplete element within getAsObject() method

Tags: primefaces, autocomplete, converters, pojo

I have a `p:autoComplete` PF element to deal with a POJO-suggestions list for which I've created a `Converter` class to map POJOs into Strings and vice versa.

```
<p:autoComplete value="#{bean.pojoTargetList}" completeMethod="#{bean.getPOJOFilteredList}" var="pojo" itemLabel="#{pojo.name}"
itemValue="#{pojo}" converter="pojoConverter" />
```

The thing is I know how to procceed to map from a POJO to a String (`getAsString()`method) but not how to do to map from a String to a POJO (`getAsObject()`method).

```
@FacesConverter("pojoConverter")
public class POJOConverter implements Converter {

@Override
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext arg0, UIComponent uiComponent, String value) {
    // ?        
    return pojo;
}

@Override
public String getAsString(FacesContext arg0, UIComponent uiComponent, Object assetTag) {
    String _return = null;
    ...
    return _return;
}
```

Maybe I'm wrong but my understanding is that the `uiComponent` param of the `getAsObject()` method is a reference to the `p:autoComplete` PF element. If so, I could have access to the POJO-suggestions list. Therefore, I could iterate on it and and find the POJO object matching the `value` param.

I'd really appreciate if someone could explain how can I access the pojo suggesion list of the `p:autocomplete` element from the `getAsObject()`method.

UPDATE:
Maybe I'm wrong but my understanding is that the `uiComponent` param of the `getAsObject()` method is a reference to the `p:autoComplete` PF element. If so, I could have access to `bean.getPOJOFilteredList`. Therefore, I could iterate on `bean.getPOJOFilteredList` and find the POJO object matching the `value` param.

Comment: Why not just use one of Omnifaces' converters? They've thought about all this.

Answer (score 1):

You can have access to the suggestion list and iterate it, by getting the completeMethod from the component and invoke it like this:

```
MethodExpression method = ((AutoComplete) component).getCompleteMethod();
List<Object> items = (List) method.invoke(facesContext.getELContext(), null);
for(Object item : items)
    if(item.equals(value))
       return item;
```

Now in your completeMethod you can add

```
public List<Object> yourAutoCompleteMethod(String query){
    if(query == null) return list;
    else
       //fetch your data//
       return list;
 }
```

so the converter will immediately get the list that you previously calculated.
By this way you have access to the suggestion list, without any injections or other mapping. It is plug and play.

Comment: This will only work if the method will return ALL results (which will not help performance on large data sets).

Comment: No the method will return the exact suggestion list, that was given to the user. You just need to add if(inputString == null) return list; at the top of the complete method. The list will be already filled with the suggestion from the previous call.

Comment: Aren't you passing null as the search query?

Comment: Yeah but here is the completeMethod `public List<Object> autoCompleteMethod(String query){ if(query == null) return list; else // do my query and get data//;  }` So the first time you call the method and give the string it fills the list, and when the converter calls the method it just returns the list

Comment: So, it will depend on the method to return ALL results (which we don't do as we potentially are dealing with large data sets).

Comment: Exactly. We usually work with chunks of the ALL set. Even if you want to return ALL records with null, you can replace the null argument in the invoke method with the "" (empty string). You can determine in your web.xml how you handle empty string from client.

Comment: I found your implementation very useful
Actually is very efficient and cost saving for the application resources @billtsi

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a `Converter` needs access to the objects he is expected to return. An implementation may look like this:

```
@FacesConverter("userConverter")
public class UserConverter implements Converter {

    @Inject
    UserDirectory userDirectory;

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String uid) {
        return uid == null || uid.isEmpty() ? null : userDirectory.findByUid(uid);
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object user) {
        final String uid = user instanceof User ? ((User) user).getUid() : null;
        return StringUtils.defaultIfEmpty(uid, "");
    }
}
```

The auto-complete method must be implemented independently and should return a list of the particular objects based on some partial input, being case-insensitive, etc.:

```
public List<User> autoCompleteUser(String queryString) {

    // implement custom retrieval / filter logic

    return filteredUsers;
}
```

Comment: What I'm setting out is to access the `bean.getPOJOFilteredList` from _UIComponent_ parameter within the `getAsObject()` method. And what you suggest is using an injected property to have access to such list. It's not what I'm looking for. See my update, please.

Comment: In your case, the concrete `UIComponent` will be of type `org.primefaces.component.autocomplete.AutoComplete`. Other components internally reference a model that contains all option, but `autoComplete` recieves them dynamically utilizing the `completeMethod`. I doubt that `AutoComplete` holds a reference to your bean.